# Descobrir qual branch tem uma certa tag - Git

Tags: git

Tenho um repositório com diversas branches, e cada branch possui várias tags. Quero descobrir qual branch possui uma certa tag "nome_da_tag". Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando:

```
git branch --contains tags/<nome-tag>
```

Substitua `<nome-tag>` pela tag que você está procurando.